# use VBA to generate a unique document ID number

Tags: excel, vba

I have the below code that compiles workbooks named 1-100 that are generated by a seperate piece of code. What i'm looking for is a way to create a unique id name for the compiled document. Ideally something like
(the date the code was executed DD/MM/YYYY), (The users windows name), unique 6-8 digit code
Looking forward to seeing if anyone can help

```
       Dim wb As Workbook, wbAll As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wss As Worksheet
Dim x As Integer, wsSummary, t As Long

Set wbAll = Workbooks.Add

For t = 1 To 100
    Set wb = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next    'ignore any error
    Set wb = Workbooks("Book" & t)
    On Error GoTo 0         'cancel OERN as soon as possible
    If Not wb Is Nothing Then
        For Each ws In wb.Sheets
            ws.Move after:=wbAll.Sheets(wbAll.Sheets.Count)
        Next
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Just use Date (YY_MM_DD) and Time (HH_MM) (24 hour of course) plus a random number formatted as you wish plus whatever other information you want if you need to identify user/machine the file was created by/on.  e.g.  USERNN_MACHINEZZ_YY_MM_DD_HH_MM_12345678.  Put the fields in the order you require if sorting at a later time will be relevant.

Comment: Your code does nothing related to what you need. Please, post the code you've tried.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns  I rather think it is the t in 'Set wb = Workbooks("Book" & t)' that the op wants to be a unique identifier.  It would be helpful if the OP could clarify.

Comment: @freeflow I think the `t` is how OP compiles the 1-100 workbooks and then after compiling, wants to generate a unique id. Anyways, to get username use `Environ("username")` and to get a really unique id, combine it `Now()` to get a timestamp in seconds. Combining these 2 facts probably should work as unique ID as @freeflow suggested